# Writing Java code snippets in Visual Studio Code in json

Tags: java, json, visual-studio-code, code-snippets

I'd like to add some Java code snippets for Visual Studio Code, to speed up things that I commonly use, e.g. `System.out.println()` but the snippets are written in json, which I have no experience of. Can anybody help me with how to structure these Java snippets, and how you actually use them when programming?

This was my own attempt:

```
"Print to console":
{
    "prefix": "System",
    "body" : ["System.out.println("],
    "description": "Print to the console"
}
```

Though I don't know whether I've written it wrong or whether I'm not accessing the snippet correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets

> You can define your own snippets for specific languages. To open up a snippet file for editing, open User Snippets under File > Preferences (Code > Preferences on Mac) and select the language for which the snippets should appear.

After open up java.json using the step described above, you should see an example commented.

To fix your snippet, it should be:

```
"Print to Console": {
    "prefix": "System",
    "body": [
        "System.out.println(\"$1\");"
    ],
    "description": "Print to the console"
}
```

As you type System on vscode, you will see the IntelliSense to give you the suggestion.

Comment: You don't need to escape the inner "s if you use ' there instead so "System.out.println('$1');"

Comment: Thanks for the example! For anyone else looking, placing $0 inside the brackets means that your cursor will start there when the snippet is added.